# Angularjs code not running in anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I wrote an anonymous javascript function that dynamically loads jQuery and Angular. However, my angular code is not running for some reason. The code works find until i hit my `main` function. I then try to make an http request and print the results in my angular controller, but theyre not printing for some reason.. Can someone help? Here are my fiddle and code:

https://jsfiddle.net/5f44yb7k/1/

Thanks in advance!

```
(function() {

  var jQuery;
  var jquery_tag = document.createElement('script');
  var angular_tag = document.createElement('script');

  function getJqueryTag() {
     console.log('getting jquery tag');
     jquery_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
     jquery_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js");
     jquery_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
     (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(jquery_tag);
     if(jquery_tag.onload) { //ensure angular loads after jQuery
            getAngularTag();
     }

  }

  function getAngularTag() {
    console.log('now getting angular tag...');
    angular_tag.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    angular_tag.setAttribute("src", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.8/angular.min.js");
    angular_tag.onload = scriptLoadHandler;
    (document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] || document.documentElement).appendChild(angular_tag);
  }

    getJqueryTag();


  function scriptLoadHandler() {
    if(window.jQuery) {
      jQuery = window.jQuery
      main();
    }
  }

  function main() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) { 
      console.log('now in main function'); //this prints fine
      var test = angular.module('test', []);

      function main_controller($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20in%20(select%20woeid%20from%20geo.places(1)%20where%20text%3D%22fairfax%2C%20va%22)&format=json&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys')
          .success(function(data) {
            console.log('---data returned---'); //not printing
            console.log(data); //not printing 
          })
          .error(function(data) {
            console.log('error: ' + data);
          });
      }
    }); 
  }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular is falling out of scope. You'll need to call the bootstrap function to get angular up and running if you're loading it in this fashion.

I've never loaded it this way, but see: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap, specifically the section on Manual Initialization.

Comment: Did you get this running? If so, can you post what you changed?